# (Python) Replace array of string elements

Tags: python-3.x

I want to replace an array of string elements，but have a problem:

This is correct!!

[image]

However，this is error:

[image]

It seem replace first char....

Thanks to your help.

Comment: Don't post image of your code. Copy and paste the code in the question

Comment: thanks everyone~~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to specify dtype to get the expected behavior, else it will choose minimum size,
i think it is choosing chararray and you are trying add numbers/strings.

either use astype or numpy.array(data, dtype="") to set dtype, look at the syntax of numpy.arry below

```
numpy.array(object, dtype=None, copy=True, order='K', subok=False, ndmin=0)
```

set dtype to string/integer/float whatever you need, refere doucmentation for exact use

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to replace some strings in the list with some numbers. You can do this easily with list comprehension like this.

```
data = ['C', 'C', 'W', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'W', 'C', 'W', 'H']

data = [15 if x == 'C' else 30 if x == 'W' else x for x in data]

# Output : [15, 15, 30, 15, 'H', 'H', 30, 15, 30, 'H']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `numpy` with method array https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.array.html

The constructure has `dtype`, If not given, then the type will be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence.

So:

```
>>> data
['C', 'W', 'C', 'C', 'W', 'H']
>>> values = numpy.array(data)
>>> values
array(['C', 'W', 'C', 'C', 'W', 'H'], dtype='<U1')
```

`values` with `dtype='<U1'`, that mean unicode length 1

Solution is set `dtype` is Unicode with length you want:

```
>>> values = numpy.array(data, dtype='<U256')
>>> values
array(['C', 'W', 'C', 'C', 'W', 'H'], dtype='<U256')
>>> values[values=='C'] = 15
>>> values
array(['15', 'W', '15', '15', 'W', 'H'], dtype='<U256')
```

That's right!